# Getting pixels' scale in images from depth/disparity map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Is there any way to calculate the scale of pixels of an image in centimeter(or so) from depth map or preferably disparity map of the images taken with stereo cameras?

Comment: the camera intrinsic parameters include that information. Typical approaches to compute them are "camera calibration" methods.

Comment: @Micka To my knowledge, the scale of pixels has a positive correlation with the depth of the pixels so I don't get how the static `camera intrinsic parameters` is going to help!? also, I am familiar with the camera calibration which once its parameters computed they are constant, how can we compute the variable pixel scales over constant factors?

Comment: so you dont mean the pixel size on the chip? To compute the pixel size for a known depth you can shoot rays through the 4 boundary corners of the pixel and evaluate the quad size for a given depth on those rays. You'll need the static camera intrinsic parameters (calibration) to do that.

Comment: @Micka If there was a shooting ray device, it would need HUGE precision to ray at specific corners of random pixels which presents a random distance and besides that it would be a very costly(money-wise) operation! I am looking for a geometric method to estimate the scale from what we already know from cameras and depth info.

Comment: I meant virtual rays... just like computing the 3d point location from your depth value (you virtually shoot a ray through the center of your pixel and stop at distance depth). It's just mathematics... the formula isnt so hard to compute if you know about basic projective geometry...

Comment: Ok @Micka I got what you mean, to admit it, I just don't know how to do that, I am more of a programmer person than a mathematician one, I have already put a question on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913944/how-to-compute-estimate-the-image-pixels-scale-from-disparity-depth-map-from-a) community about this problem of mine.

Comment: When I find the time I'll compose that formula for you, but not from my mobile :D

Comment: @Micka Thanks, It's nice of you :)